# ASP.Net MVC: How to associate a role with action from my custom UI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, role

often we attach role with action like below way

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, SuperUser")]

[Authorize(Users="Jacquo, Steve", Roles="Admin, SuperUser")]
```

Users : Comma-separated list of usernames that are allowed to access the action method.

Roles : Comma-separated list of role names. To Access the action method, users must be in at least one of these roles.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Producer")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult Details(int id) {
    // Only available to users who are Producers AND Editors
}
```

now see authorize and role name is hard coded with action method. suppose action Details is associated with admin role which is hard coded but how could i attach more role to details action or remove any role from details action at run time. i guess it is not possible because asp.net mvc not providing anything built in.

i search google to see that anyone does it anything such as what i am looking for. unfortunately found no similar write up.

so i need some guidance that how could i develop a UI from where admin can associate role with action instead of hard coding at development time.

so tell me your think how could i associate a role or multiple roles with action from a custom UI.

also tell me how could i check at run time that user has that role when user try to access a specific action.

please discuss in details for designing this part what i am looking for. still it is not clear to you what i am looking for then tell me i will try to explain the same in more details.

thanks

Comment: anyone can discuss or give me direction to design what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First: in every controller you should create a user object in controller constructor. like this:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    ApplicationUser user;
    public MyController ()
    {
        user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
    }
```

Then you could use user object anywhere in your controller methods.
"how could i develop a UI from where admin can associate role": in razor view use :

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                    {}
```

"how could i associate a role or multiple roles with action from a custom UI":
No need to that. When you create user in controller, you have access user all roles in controller methods.
"how could i check at run time that user has that role":
Use

```
if(user.IsInRole("Admin"))
```

Comment: i just see your code where you are creating user instance in controller ctor......but why i need to create user instance in every controller ?

Comment: `if(user.IsInRole("Admin"))` how to check user against multiple roles. here you check user has admin role. suppose if user need to check against multiple of role. what code i need to write.

Comment: ''why i need to create user instance in every controller ?": because every time your views comes to controller , you have new instance of that controller.

Comment: "user need to check against multiple of role" : use '@if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("usertype2"))'

Comment: instead of creating user ever time i can check user's role and action name from db just pass user id like `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()`  if i found user role has a access defined in db then allow user to go forward, otherwise redirect user to error page.

Comment: Yes you can. But it is bad habit to send request to db every time. Also you have to send request for every use instead of having that all over your controller and its views.

Comment: suppose userA access controller MyController then ctor will be called and say when you come again to MyController then again ctor will be called....so where is the benefit of creating user from ctor. the way u wrote the code db call can be minimize to some extent but not to great extent.